# Have there been attempts to train LLMs using generated "I don't know" data to decrease hallucinations?

Tags: llm, hallucination

Correct me if I am wrong, but I assume that hallucinations can be primarily blamed on the training data underrepresenting responses that specifically state that someone doesn't know a specific fact. On the internet (the source of most training data AFAIK) either you know a certain fact and you share it, or you don't know it and you don't mention your lack of knowledge. Thus LLMs seem to replicate the training data, rarely answering with "I don't know" responses.

It would be fairly easy to generate a big set of training data that's basically countless of questions for which there are probably no known answers with a simple "I don't know" response.

Examples: "What is the average height of elephants in northern India? I don't know", "What is a unique thing about Soest, the Netherlands? I don't know", "What did the US president eat for breakfast yesterday? I don't know".

Have there been any attempts to train an LLM with such data and did it decrease the incidence rate of hallucinations?

Comment: related: [Is there a way to get Poe.com's ChatGPT to consistently reply "I don't know" or "I can't do that" instead of making stuff up?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/41/33)

Answer (score 11):

> It would be fairly easy to generate a big set of training data that's basically countless of questions for which there are probably no known answers with a simple "I don't know" response.

It may actually be not that easy to generate such a large list of unanswerable questions. Furthermore, training some LLM on it would likely cause the LLM to output "I don't know" far too frequently, since the conditional probability of "I don't know" given any other token would become very high.

We could try to build a list of answerable questions and use it while answering, e.g. see [Open-Domain Question Answering with Pre-Constructed Question Spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.08337), but it may be hard to reliably scale for the entire web.

As an additional difficulty, even if an LLM doesn't know the answer to "What is the average height of elephants in northern India?", it [may know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OYPr.png) the answer to "What is the average height of elephants in India?", in which case the user may still be interested in it instead of simply being given some "I don't know".

Note that addressing unanswerable questions has been a long-standing issue in question-answering systems, e.g. see this ACL 2018 paper: [Know What You Don’t Know: Unanswerable Questions for SQuAD](https://aclanthology.org/P18-2124.pdf) by [Pranav Rajpurkar](https://aclanthology.org/people/p/pranav-rajpurkar/), [Robin Jia](https://aclanthology.org/people/r/robin-jia/), [Percy Liang](https://aclanthology.org/people/p/percy-liang/). Also, there exists a plethora of recent [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.06085) on hallucination reduction for LLMs.

Comment: Thanks for type of answer I was looking for with interesting resources to look at! My thinking was that they don't need to all be perfectly unanswerable, as long as they would skew the model away from plausible guesses (even if those guesses might sometimes be correct, would rather have only a fraction of the responses if I could trust the responses more than we do now). But yeah, no doubt there will be far more refined approaches, but after pondering this idea for awhile now I figured I might get great responses here

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, no such work has been done (to my knowledge).

Let's go back to your question. Hallucinations come from a prediction that does not meet the historical representation of actual events. Thereby, its impossible to train it with anti-questions (for all known & unknown combinations). But I like your thinking, and its on point!

If you have a use case, one of the simplest way you can ask it to not make up a response is by simply appending something along the lines of:

<your data, your personal (eg: Therapy Bot)>

Only answer data based on the information above.

What will happen is that the Bot/response will automatically say 'I do not know the answer to this'.

Obviously, you need to run a number of tests to make sure, but it has worked well for me and a bot that I ran.